# Strange url adds in wp comments avatar

Tags: php, wordpress

I use my own custom walker for wp comments.
And when i try output url new default custom avatar pic i got prefix to url.
Something like i1.wp.com.
So when:

```
$new_default_icon =get_bloginfo('template_directory') . '/img/default-avatar.jpg'
echo get_avatar( $comment, 65, $new_default_icon, 'Author’s gravatar' );
```

i got:

```
http://i1.wp.com/localhost/some-site/wp-content/themes/some-theme/img/default-avatar.jpg
```

why that happens, and how can i avoid this

Comment: Do you have the Jetpack Plugin activated? Deactivated Photon in Jetpack and then try again.

Comment: No, dnt have this plugin and dnt need

Comment: Please try the solution mentioned in this thread (custom default avatar on localhost): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14088040/wordpress-custom-default-avatar-on-localhost

Comment: Yes, that helps. Thanks

Comment: Ok, ill mark it as a duplicate. Please keep in mind that this workaround is for testing purposes only!